# (UE4) Save a lambda function in the header

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

i am currently defining a lamda function which i want to save in my header file.

```
void FURealisticGraspingEditorModule::OnPreviewCreation(const TSharedRef<IPersonaPreviewScene>& InPreviewScene)
{
    TSharedRef<IPersonaToolkit> PersonaToolKitRef = InPreviewScene.Get().GetPersonaToolkit();
    auto lambda = [PersonaToolKitRef]() { return PersonaToolKitRef.Get(); };
    DebugMeshComponent = PersonaToolKitRef.Get().GetPreviewMeshComponent();
}
```

The lamda variable should get saved in the header. I did not manage to do this yet and now i am curious if this is even possible. I tried auto and TFunctionRef. Maybe there is a hint you guys can give me to achive this or even another way to save this call in a variable.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Are these lines in global scope? Why not simply write a function instead of lambda?

Comment: This is a function which gets called whenever a IPersonaPreviewScene gets created. Now i would like to store its PersonaToolkit (which is an Abstract class) in a variable.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. `auto foo = [](){return 1;};` creates a variable, which stores a function object. This function can then be called like any other function: `int a = foo();`. Here, `lambda` variable dies at the end of `OnPreviewCreation` function. You don't use it anywhere, so it's probably optimized away by compiler. And you capture `PersonaToolKitRef` by value, so you use a copy of it in lambda body.

Comment: I would like to define my variable lambda in my .h file so i can use this lambda function anywhere in my cpp file. And this is my problem. I do not know a way to store the lambda function in a variable, which is declared in a header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to declare a lambda variable separately from initialising it you need to store it in `std::function`. The type of a lambda is only known at the point you create it so its not possible to declare a variable to store it separately.

For example:

```
auto a = []{ return 1; }; // OK

auto b; // invalid, can't declare as auto as the type can't be deduced
b = []{ return 1; };

std::function< bool() > c;
c = []{ return 1; }; // OK, we can store a lambda in std::function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *define* (and initialise) your lambda in your header file if you compile for C++17 and declare it `inline`.

At least, I *think* it works for lambdas, try it.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas can be stored in function pointers without too much effort like that:

In header:
`double (*lambda)(double);`

In the .cpp file:
`lambda = [&](double a) { return 2*a; };`

The trouble with this approach is that the defined type of lambda cannot be dynamic. What I mean by that is the assigned lambda needs to match the type defined in the header, so it must have the same return type and, type-wise, exactly the same list of arguments.

And one more little thing. In C++ you are not allowed to re-declare neither functions nor variables in the same scope. If you define a variable directly in a header file and happen to include it into more than one source file, you will get an unpleasant surprise in form of crazy errors. In a header file, define your variable using `extern` and then define it normally in ONE source file in order to avoid trouble.